# Mongodb with docker-compose - create user

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "2.0"
services:
  mongo_container:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: testdb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongodata:/data/db
```

And this in my spring configuration:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=example
spring.data.mongodb.database=testdb
```

But everytime when I try to connect my app to Mongo I get following error in Docker console:

```
mongo_container_1  | 2020-03-31T07:37:24.803+0000 I  ACCESS   [conn2] SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for root on testdb from client 172.29.0.1:36628 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user "root" for db "testdb"
```

What am I doing wrong?
I tried to remove all containers with `docker system prune` and run it again but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Did you try [to enable access control](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/enable-authentication/#enable-auth)?

Comment: try with `spring.data.mongodb.database=admin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the following line in your application.properties :

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
```

[From docker-hub mongodb readme](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) :

> MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME, MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
>
> These variables, used in conjunction, create a new user and set that
> user's password. **This user is created in the admin authentication
> database** and given the role of root, which is a "superuser" role.

And for database :

> MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE
> This variable allows you to specify the name of a database to be used
> for creation scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.js ... MongoDB
> is fundamentally designed for "create on first use", **so if you do not
> insert data with your JavaScript files, then no database is created.**

In MongoDB, when authentication is enabled you allways authenticate against a particular database (by default admin), then connect and use another one.
That's why there are two different properties : authentication-database (to authenticate against) and database (the one to use)